# Removal of special character in string in C++

Tags: c++

I have the followoing

```
string myStr = "myname-abc";

string myStr1 = strstr(myStr.c_str(), "-");
```

now in myStr1 i have -abc. But i don't want "-" infront of it i want to have "abc" how do i do that using string data type.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t pos = myStr.find('-');
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    myStr1 = myStr.substr(pos + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string myStr1 = strstr(mStr.c_str(), "-") + 1;
```

or if you want to avoid converting to C style strings:

```
string myStr1(m_Str, m_Str.find('-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm following, but you want to erase the first element?

```
str.erase(0, 1); // erases 1 element starting from position 0
```

Also, if you just want to erase everything up to `-`:

```
str.erase(0, str.find('-') + 1);
```

If the data you are feeding the program isn't guaranteed to have a `-` somewhere, you should check the return value of `str.find('-')` for `string::npos`, the return value when no occurence is found.

Answer (score 0):

This program outputs

abc abc

```
int main()
{
    string myStr = "myname-abc";
    string myStr1 = strstr(myStr.c_str(), "abc");

    int index = 0;
    while(myStr[index++] != '-'){}
    string myStr2 = myStr.substr(index);

    cout << myStr1 << " " << myStr2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string myStr("myname-abc");
std::string myStr1(++std::find(myStr.begin(), myStr.end(), '-'),
                   myStr.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking for, it's to remove instance of "-" from the string? If so, the following will also work..

```
string foo("-abc");
string::size_type fm = foo.find('-');
while (fm != string::npos)
{
  foo.erase(foo.begin() + fm);
  fm = foo.find('-', fm); // find the next instance of "-"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 void main()
 {
 clrscr();
 char a[30];
 cout<<"enter any string ";
 cin.get(a,30);
 char b[30];
 for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
 if(a[i]!='!' && a[i]!='#'&& a[i]!='@' && a[i]!='$' && a[i]!='%' && a[i]!='^' && a[i]!='&'    && a[i]!='*' && a[i]!='?')
 {
 b[i]=a[i];
 cout<<b[i];
 } }
 getch();
  }
```